# Реализация IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Решил поиграть с интерфейсом IEnumerable. Создал свой класс для массива и реализовал метод GetEnumerator. Но почему без public в 27 строке возникает ошибка? Тем более что где-то читал что при реализации интерфейса наоборот public нельзя писать.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Interfaces
{   

    public class IntArray: IEnumerable
    {
        private int[] a;
        public IntArray(int n)
        {
            a = new int[n];
        }

        public int this[int i] 
        {
            get
            {
                return a[i];
            }
            set
            {
                a[i] = value;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() // Почему без public ошибка?
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                yield return a[i];
        }

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        IntArray x = new IntArray(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            x[i] = 2 * i;
        foreach (var t in x) Console.Write(t + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: public не пишется при объявлении интерфейса. При реализации интерфейса в классе - методы интерфейса обязаны быть public

Comment: При _явной_ реализации интерфейса public не пишут (но пишется имя интерфейса через точку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы неправильно прочитали. Интерфейс это общий протокол он всегда используется public  для взаимодействия общими поведение.Потому что интерфейс это открытый протокол поведение. (Ну то есть это предвидение абстрактных поведения.)

**дополнительная информация**

1. [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)
2. [Habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/278561/)

   ```
    public interface ITest
    {
       void GetName();
    }


    public class Person : ITest
    {
        public void GetName()
        {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Я кажется понял. Я кое-что спутал. Вот случай в котором написание public приводит к ошибке. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0106

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко внутренние интерфейсы когда пишешь сигнатура метода не надо дополнительно писать 'Public' потому что он автоматически реализуется как 'Public'. хорошенько смотрите Вы запутались просто.

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко если не поняли хотите объясню дополнительно ?вот автоматически реализация я поставил в пример.

Comment: Вот если взять такой класс class Circle: IDrawToPrinter, IDrawToScreen и оба интерфейса имеют метод Draw. И если мы хотим чтобы в классе было 2 метода Draw придется писать void IDrawToPrinter.Draw и вот тут с public уже не компилируется. И я походу просто спутал с этим примером... https://ideone.com/Mv3nhd

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко да тогда надо разделить то есть надо привести интерфейсу которым ты хочешь воспользоваться поведением. если что отвечу удачи.